# C multidimensional array not accepting modifications to its members

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I am very new to C. I was trying to write a very basic matrix program for practice.

The way the matrix works is that it is created with a given number of rows and columns, and then it callocs a single one dimensional array with enough slots (rows * cols slots... You get the idea). Then to access a slot, you call a `matrix_getcell` on the matrix with the cell and it returns a pointer to the cell.

Here is matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct matrix matrix;
struct matrix {
    uint rows;
    uint cols;
    double *data;
};

matrix *matrix_new(uint rows, uint cols) {
    matrix *n = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
    if (n == NULL) exit(1);

    n->data = calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(*(n->data)));
    if (n->data == NULL) exit(1);

    n->rows = rows;
    n->cols = cols;

    return n;
}

void matrix_del(matrix *m) {
    if (m == NULL) return;

    free(m->data);
    free(m);
}

double *matrix_getcell(matrix *m, uint row, uint col) {
    if (row >= m->rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid row: %d\n", row);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (col >= m->cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid col: %d\n", col);
        exit(1);
    }

    uint pos = (m->rows * row) + col;

    return &(m->data[pos]);
}

#endif
```

and here is main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "matrix.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    matrix *m = matrix_new(3, 3);

            /* I know that a 3x3 will have 9 cells, so
             * fill them up with successive numbers
             */
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        m->data[i] = i;
    }

            /* Now, run through each cell, row by column
             * and print out the coords and the contents.
             */
    for (uint r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (uint c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            double *cur = matrix_getcell(m, r, c);
            printf("(%d, %d): %.3d\n", r, c, *cur);
        }
    }

    matrix_del(m);

    return 0;
}
```

What I tried to do with this was to initialize EACH separate cell to a successive number, such that when I for-looped over it the second time it would hopefully have outputedd:

```
(0, 0): 0
(0, 1): 1
(0, 2): 2
(1, 0): 3
(1, 1): 4
(1, 2): 5
(2, 0): 6
(2, 1): 7
(2, 2): 8
```

But instead, it outputs

```
(0, 0): 0
(0, 1): 0
(0, 2): 0
(1, 0): 1
(1, 1): 1
(1, 2): 1
(2, 0): 2
(2, 1): 2
(2, 2): 2
```

I have added (and then removed) code to test whether `matric_getcell` was returning incorrect results (it doesn't seem to be). I have changed the datatype, I have tried casting... I don't know what else to try.

Why does it seem to be setting each column to the same number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `matrix_getcell` method has a bug inside when you calculate the position of the cell.

```
double *matrix_getcell(matrix *m, uint row, uint col) {
    ...
    // Should be (m_cols * row) + col.
    uint pos = (m->rows * row) + col;

    return &(m->data[pos]);
}
```

Another bug is there when you are printing the doubles. You should be using `%f` instead of `%d` to print doubles.

```
//                   v--- "%d" is the problem here
printf("(%d, %d): %.3d\n", r, c, *cur);
```

Comment: Thanks! I would estimate that about 75 percent of the bugs that plague me in C trace back to using wrong format strings. Too used to java I guess.

Comment: @scott_fakename, No problem. Yes, you need to pay attention to the specifier in C. If I remember correctly, wrong specifier may cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need

`double **data;` //to treat `data` as a 2d matrix

In `matrix_new` use following to allocate matrix

```
n->data = calloc(rows, sizeof(double*));
if (n->data == NULL) exit(1);    
for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++) {
    n->data[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(double));
}
```

And to avoid memory leak, free it using

```
void matrix_del(matrix *m) {
  if (m == NULL) return;

  uint r=m->rows;
  uint c=m->cols;

  for(int i = 0; i <r ; i++)
    free(m->data[i]);

   free(m);
}
```